# New monitor has red/green ghosting around moving objects

Tags: display, visual-artifacts

I bought an Acer KB242HYL monitor and whenever something moves on it there's red/green smearing on the moving object. I tried adjusting the refresh rate and using a different HDMI cable and none worked. I'm on the latest drivers for both the monitor and my GPU (GTX 1650). I tried increasing the over-drive setting, which did slightly reduce the red smearing but it also made everything ghost and have weird artifacts instead. The monitor is a VA, 75Hz, 4ms GtG panel. Is the monitor just defective or is it some sort of software issue?

Comment: (1) Try to run the [Blur Busters Ghosting Test](https://www.testufo.com/ghosting) in your browser. If you have no issues, you’ll see the green “Ready” signal. (2) Did you try another cable?

Comment: @harrymc I tried the ghosting test and there was ghosting plus some red/green on the leading and trailing edges of the ufos. I tried connecting the monitor via vga and also tried a different pc but no dice.

Comment: In the monitor's the on-screen display, activate the overdrive function (if it has one). Try also to adjust settings with names such as Perfect Clear, Dynamic Contrast, Motion Smoothing, and Noise Reduction. If nothing helps, returning the monitor to be reimbursed is one solution.

Comment: As I stated I did try adjusting the over-drive setting but that didn't help. My monitor didn't have any of the other settings you mentioned though. I've already returned the monitor to the place I bought it from, but due to their protocol, they need to send it to their repair/service department before they have the permission to let me get my money back (unlikely) or exchange it for another monitor (a bit less unlikely).